# How can if/elif/else be replaced with min() and max()?

Tags: python, if-statement, max, min

Working on an exercise from [MIT's OpenCourseWare 6.01SC](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-01sc-introduction-to-electrical-engineering-and-computer-science-i-spring-2011/index.htm). Problem 3.1.5:

> Define a function `clip(lo, x, hi)` that returns `lo` if `x` is less than `lo`, returns `hi` if `x` is greater than `hi`, and returns `x` otherwise. You can assume that `lo < hi`. ...don't use `if`, but use `min` and `max`.

Reformulated in English, if `x` is the least of the arguments, return `lo`; if `x` is the greatest of the arguments, return `hi`; otherwise, return `x`. Thus:

```
def clip(lo, x, hi):
    if min(lo, x, hi) == x:
        return lo
    elif max(lo, x, hi) == x:
        return hi
    else:
        return x
```

Maybe I am not understanding the problem correctly, but I can't figure out how to return a result without using `if` at all. How can the function be modified to remove the if/elif/else statements?

[Link to original problem 3.1.5](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-01sc-introduction-to-electrical-engineering-and-computer-science-i-spring-2011/python-tutorial/part-3/MIT6_01SCS11_py3_1_5.pdf)

[Link to previous problem 3.1.4 (for context)](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-01sc-introduction-to-electrical-engineering-and-computer-science-i-spring-2011/python-tutorial/part-3/MIT6_01SCS11_py3_1_4.pdf)

EDIT:

Comments/answers to this question helped me realize that my original plain English reformulation wasn't a great way to think about the problem. A better way to think about it would have been to determine which of the arguments is between the other two.

Comment: Hint: Pass the result of a `max` call to a `min` call. This problem unfortunately has such a simple solution that any more than that is basically writing it for you.

Comment: Spoiler: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1336636/18486

Comment: @ShadowRanger doh! i was thinking about it too hard. thank you for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One line of code:

```
#! python3.8

def clip(lo, x, hi):
    return max(min(x, hi), lo)

print(clip(1, 2, 3))
print(clip(2, 1, 3))
print(clip(1, 3, 2))

# Output
# 2
# 2
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return this formula:

```
x + lo + hi - max(x, lo, hi) - min(x, lo, hi)
```

Arguing by cases:

Case 1:

```
If min(lo, x, hi) = lo and max(lo, x, hi) = hi
  x + lo + hi - max(x, lo, hi) - min(x, lo, hi) ==> x + lo + hi - hi - lo ==> x
```

Case 2:

```
If min(lo, x, hi) = lo and max(lo, x, hi) = x
  x + lo + hi - max(x, lo, hi) - min(x, lo, hi) ==> x + lo + hi - x - lo ==> hi
```

Case 3:

```
If min(lo, x, hi) = x and max(lo, x, hi) = hi
  x + lo + hi - max(x, lo, hi) - min(x, lo, hi) ==> x + lo + hi - hi - x ==> lo
```

The formula returns the expected answer on all possible cases.

Comment: If you can assume the caller didn't lie about `lo` being lower than `hi`, it can be simpler than this (this is a fine way to find the middle of three arbitrary numbers, but it's more than needed when clipping to a range).

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. The answer from @MrGeek did help me understand what the question was asking. At that point, calling max() inside min() made total sense. Thanks, all!

Comment: @ShadowRanger I see your point, this was a refresher, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go, a value checking function without using if-else at all. While block will only run for once so there is no redundancy.

```py
def clip(lo, x, hi):
    low = (min(lo, x) == x)
    high = (max(x, hi) == x)
    while low:
        return lo
    while high:
        return hi
    return x
```

EDIT: I don't know why he downvoted my code